# 401 Unauthorized error when retrieving dependencies from Sonatype Nexus in Docker

Tags: docker, maven, nexus, nexus3

I am currently running Sonatype Nexus on Docker, and I am facing an issue when attempting to retrieve a dependency from it. I consistently encounter a '401 Unauthorized' error. Interestingly, I am able to successfully deploy artifact to Nexus without any issues.

The problem could be related to the use of HTTP instead of HTTPS for the connection. Could this be the cause of the '401 Unauthorized' error?